# How do TCDL tags work with the GraphQL CD endpoint?

Tags: content-delivery, tcdl, graphql

**How do `<TCDL>` tags work with the GraphQL-based Content Delivery API(s)?**

I understand historically customer Content Management code and/or the Default Building Blocks would transform Component links in Component fields or rich text format areas to the appropriate platform-agnostic `<tcdl>` markup.

*And depending if you're developing for .NET or Java, the appropriate attribute would be added (either in templating or publishing). Mainly 'runat="server"' was added for .NET.*

Later we had **REL**, as a more platform agnostic version of **TCDL**.

### Questions:

1. With GraphQL, does `TCDL` still apply?
2. Or perhaps, it's better to ask *can* it still apply if using rendered/raw content?
3. If so, can we still create custom TCDL tags? I can see the [documentation for Sites 9.1](https://docs.rws.com/783502/604388/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/creating-custom-tcdl-tags), but not later versions.
4. And does TCDL behavior differ between data pipeline (template-less) content or the Sites 9.6 semantic content modeling?

For background, I mentioned custom TCDL tags in this answer https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/21797/46 but didn't know if this is still possible in recent versions, or even recommended going forward.

Answer (score 1):

When requesting content over the Public Content API using GraphQL, you can control whether tcdl tags are rendered using `rawContent()` with the `renderContent` parameter set to true or false.

The [Documentation Center explains `renderContent` set to true will resolve TCDL link tags](https://docs.rws.com/816112/637061/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/graphql-request-to-render-the-links-in-a-returned-page-or-component-presentation).

To answer my original questions:

1. With GraphQL, does TCDL still apply?
   **Yes.**
2. Or perhaps, it's better to ask can it still apply if using rendered/raw content?   
   **TCDL links will render if using `rawContent(renderContent: true)`.**
3. If so, can we still create custom TCDL tags?

   **As far as the documentation is concerned, [custom TCDL tags are still a thing](https://docs.rws.com/986894/103440/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/creating-custom-tcdl-tags).**
4. Does TCDL behavior differ between data pipeline (template-less) content or the Sites 9.6 semantic content modeling?

I think you can get TCDL tags resolved in requests either way, but I'm not sure of the right syntax yet.